# How to apply css to 'text' and 'password' together

Tags: css

How apply css to 'text' and 'password' together.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input[type="text"] , input[type="password"] {
    /*css code*/   
}
```